# Access to SQL chained exception in JZ00L: Login failed ERROR

Tags: java, exception

While trying to connect to Sybase DB using `BouncyCastleProvider` I am getting the below exception using `e.printStackTrace()`. However in order to get the SQL warnings I did `e.getNextException()` but it is showing `null`. Is there any other way to get to know what are those `SQLWarnings`? I don't have access to the DB server so I cannot use various options to show the `SQLWarnings` on the server itself.

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Login failed.  Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleSQLE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleHAFailover(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at SybaseTesting.main(SybaseTesting.java:18)
```

**EDIT**
I am getting the above exception at the connection creation layer itself. So `Connection` is `null` and calling `Statement.getWarnings()` on Connection is giving NPE

Comment: That refers to [`Statement.getWarnings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings--) to be used in your Java code. Not something to be enabled on the Server side

Comment: It is throwing Exception at Connection Creation itself, Statement.getWarnings() is giving NPE since connection itself is null

Comment: Then use [`Connection.getWarnings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getWarnings--)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Connection itself is null, so COnnection.getWarnings() will give NPE.